# What is Saatarumarai and why is it done?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, dvaita, smarta

I've heard this term called Saatarumarai. But don't know anything on when, where and why it's done. Can someone please tell me

Comment: Can anyone provide an answer to help me?

Comment: https://ramanuja.org/sri/BhaktiListArchives/Article?p=oct98%2F0155.html       and also  
    https://www.kinchit.org/dharma-sandeha/thread/satrumurai/      kindly refer both the articles. Hope tht helps at the best.